# Direct a value to another page jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to jquery I know it is just a simple method to creating a function in jquery. but I am having a error in my code if anyone can help me I shall be very thankful to him.

**What I have:**
I have a table. in front of every record there are two buttons one for edit and one for delete record.

**What I am trying to do:** 
When I click button it have to direct me to other page with record id where I have my PHP query to manipulate my database record.

**This is how my table looks like:** 
[image]

**This is my html code:**

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
   <td><?php echo $inc; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['name'];  ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['father_name'];  ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['email'];  ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['contact'];  ?></td>
   <td>
     <?php echo "<button class='btn' value='".$row['id']."' onclick='update(this.value)'>Edit</button>" ?>
   </td>
   <td>
     <?php echo "<button class='btn' value='".$row['id']."' onclick='delete(this.value)'>delete</button>" ?>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

**This is my Jquery code:**

```
 function delete(str){
    $('delete.php?q='+str);
  }
```

I know something is wrong but I don't know what I will also appreciate suggestion to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ajax request for that.

```
function delete(value){

 $.ajax({
   data:{'q':value},
   type:'POST',
   url:'delele.php',
   success:function(xhr){
       console.log("record delelte");
   }
});
```

}

Comment: what is joyride? any idea.

Comment: I have not any idea, about joyride. sorry Hamza Ameer.
But i think it is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href` to redirect the page

```
function delete(str){

    window.location.href = 'delete.php?q='+ str ;

  }
```

Jquery try this:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".btn" , function() {

         var rowId = this.value;

         window.location = 'delete.php?q='+ rowId ;

    });

});
```

Comment: I am having this error  

function delete(str) any hint

Comment: Please make sure you have include the jquery header file in your head part

Comment: I updated please check the code if any issues let me know thanks

Comment: what is joyride? any idea.

Comment: Joyride is a plugin in jquery for redirect the page without scroll using div elements http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not necessary, and **window.location.replace(...)** will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

It is better than using `window.location.href =`, because `replace()` does not put the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use `location.href`. If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`.

**For example:**

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: what is joyride? any idea.